# Angular 2 ngStyle properties as Variables in less stylesheet for use with media queries

Tags: angular, properties, media-queries

How can I utilize my [ngStyle] property in my stylesheet and use like a variable for use in media queries?

Currently I can set the size, position of objects dynamically using ngStyle in the .html

```
[ngStyle]="{'margin-top': (theme.displayNameMarginTop | convertpx ),
                         'margin-left': (theme.displayNameMarginLeft | convertpx ) }"
```

however this breaks down for a responsive design as there is no way of plugging in this value into a media query, like a variable...

Using a variable... from a variabless.less file

```
@media all and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1280px) {

    .displayname-container {
        margin-top: @displayname-margintop !important;

    }
}
```

need to use the relevant property...

```
@media all and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1280px) {

.displayname-container {
    margin-top: theme.displayNameMarginTop !important;
}
```

As a result, the margin is fixed for all device sizes without the media queries and thus becomes useless to use.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue for icon size (actually font size) based on window size.

So you could grab the window information (I actually dedicated a WindowService, but for the purpose of this answer we can keep it short by skipping)

I also created a local variable, fontSize (though in your case it would be `marginTop`)

```
fontSize: number;

  constructor() {
    this.initResponsiveElements();
  }

  initResponsiveElements() {
       const width = window.screen.width; // I actually encapsulated this with service
        if(width< 544){
          this.fontSize = 20;
        }else if(width > 544 && width < 768) {
          this.fontSize = 30;
        }else if(width >=768 && width < 992) {
          this.fontSize = 40;
        }else if(width >= 992 && width <1200){
          this.fontSize = 45;
        }else{
          this.fontSize = 50;
        }
  }
```

Then inside your html, you can assign directly to property (in your case it should be `[style.margin-top.px]="marginTop"`.

```
<span class="fa fa-bookmark bookmark-icon-test"
              [style.font-size.px]="fontSize"></span>
```

If you need to create even more responsive for window resizing, then you could call function on window resize

```
 <span class="fa fa-bookmark bookmark-icon-test"
              (window:resize)="initResponsiveElements()"
              [style.font-size.px]="fontSize"></span>
```